No logro escapar barra invertida al decodificar JSON
Tengo en un campo de un JSON en la base de datos lo siguiente:
"opinion": "["APTO - Relaci\u00d3n cuota \/ ingreso suficiente"]"

El problema cuando hago:
$resultadojson = $this->_database->get_resultadoUnico();
$arrayjson=json_decode($resultadojson["datos_principal"], true);
var_dump($arrayjson);

Me devuelve null en $arrayjson, ya probe que $resultadojson trae elcampo json adecuadamente.
He probado con:
$jsonString = preg_replace('/(?<!\\\\)(\\\\\\\\)*\\\\(\\\\|")/', '$1$2', 
$resultadojson["datos_principal"]);
    
// Decodifica el JSON
$json = json_decode($jsonString, true);

Y con:
$arrayjson=json_decode($resultadojson["datos_principal"], JSON_INVALID_UTF8_IGNORE);

Pero me devuelve null

Hola Giuliano, si en la BD tenes esa cadena, entonces el problema no es la barra, sino que la cadena, ya que no es un JSON válido. Para que sea válido debería ser algo como {"opinion": "["APTO - Relaci\u00d3n cuota / ingreso suficiente"]}

tampoco @Marcos ese json tiene comillas dobles de mas ... deberia de ser asi: {"opinion": ["APTO - Relaci\u00d3n cuota \/ ingreso suficiente"]}

si alguna de las respuesta te ha servido podes marcarla como resuelta, eso te dara al menos 2 puntos de reputacion que te seran utiles en un futuro. saludos.

La respuesta es sencilla eso que ves son caracteres de escape unicode, puedes obtener una salida limpia sin agregar ningun argumento mas que el true que retornar un array asociativo:
$jsonString = '{"opinion": ["APTO - Relaci\u00d3n cuota \/ ingreso suficiente"]}';

$array = json_decode($jsonString, true);

var_dump($array);

output:
array(1) {
  ["opinion"]=>
  string(43) "APTO - RelaciÓn cuota / ingreso suficiente"
}

Cuando json_decode realiza esta decodificación, automáticamente maneja la conversión de caracteres de escape Unicode a sus representaciones de texto plano.
Con lo que debe tener cuidado es que el texto realmente sea una structutura string json de lo contrario obtendras errores de sintaxis json y no es por los caracteres de scape.
